# Using Entity Reference to show a view within a node

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type of Authors that I want to attach to the bottom of article content type. One person will be entering all the content and they need to be able to select which author box will show at the bottom of the article.

I have been able to do this with entity reference and the display shows the rendered entity. But I have a view I would like shown instead of the rendered entity and I can not make that happen. I was able to associate the author view using the Entity Views Attachment but it associated with the UID of the account signed in when the post was created how can I instead associate it with the entity reference select list field?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an entity reference field in articles that points to the content type "authors", and the view will be show on the article content type..

In your view, you should be able to add the relationship "Entity Reference: ReferencED entity" for that field name.

Then you can add your fields from the authors content type and make sure you point to the referenced entity in the field's settings.

You'll also need a contextual filter for NID "Provide default: Current Node".